# Why is INNER join not working with LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do an INNER JOIN with the SQL statement below. It works perfectly fine without an INNER JOIN, but when I do an Inner join it returns 0 results.

I am not sure what the issue is here... any help would be really appreciated.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN checkout_page ON checkout_page.customer_id = customers.customers_id 
WHERE customers.phone LIKE '%347%'
```

Comment: have you tried left join?

Comment: change to left join if there is no record for the customer in the checkout_page  table.

Comment: You probably don't have a matching customer_id in the checkout_page table. Briefly change it to an outter join and see if you get it.

Comment: Why do you assume that `INNER JOIN` doesn't work with `LIKE`? The `LIKE` operator is used in the `WHERE` clause and the `WHERE` clause is applied after the `JOIN` clause. Did you test the query **without** the `WHERE` clause? I bet it doesn't return any row.

Comment: Learn to debug!!!!  Have you checked whether that `customer_id` has entries in `checkout_page`???  It's not the problem of `JOIN` and `LIKE`.  It's the problem of your data.

Comment: What's the other query?

Comment: @SagarPanchasara Thanks! The left join fixed the solution!